# Why jQuery tries to load an image more than one time?

Tags: jquery, image, load

I want to load an image and before completely loading want if any error happens and it couldn't load it, just do some works.

For the first time, it works fine. But for the second time when I want to load another image again and when it's not available, it tries to load repeatedly.

I used :

```
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1
```

What is wrong with my code?

```
$("#av-1").load(function () {
    $("#av-1").attr('src', imagePath);
    $("#av-1").attr('alt', title);
}).attr('src', imagePath).error(function () {  

});
```

Update:

I Updated my codes to :

```
 try {
    $("#av-1").load(function () {
        $("#av-1").attr('src', imagePath);
    }).attr('src', imagePath).error(function () {
        try {
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);

}
```

But no error happened :(

[image]

Comment: If "#av-1" is your image identifier then this event may be triggered whenever you tried to load. Further codes or logic will be helpful for debugging.

Comment: Can you explain it more

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`jQuery.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), then the handler will be executed, at most, once per element per event type. This will stop your loop from occurring.

```
$("#av-1").one('load', function () {
    $("#av-1").attr('src', imagePath);
    $("#av-1").attr('alt', title);
}).attr('src', imagePath).error(function () {  
    // Log errors...
});
```

Comment: I used try catch inside of error function no error happening there

Comment: Can you elaborate, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Why would you wrap your entire `$.load` call inside a `try-catch`? Wouldn't the `$.error` catch the loading errors?